# The setInitialData function no work

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I have a customer model.

```
class Customer { 
    public CustomerName = ko.observable(null);
    public LastModifiedBy = ko.observable(null);
}
```

After I create a new instance and want to set some default value.

```
var myEntities = ko.observableArray()
var model = new Customer();
setDefault(model);
myEntities.push(model);
```

The method looks like this:

```
setDefault(m){
    m.CustomerName('Init');
    m.LastModifiedBy('Init')
}
```

But this not work. 
I can not see the data in my view.

```
data-bind="foreach:     myEntities()"
data-bind="text:     CustomerName"
```

What is the problem I got?

Comment: Define "seems not work"? Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: I can not see the data in my view. In <tbody data-bind="foreach:     myEntities() > and <td data-bind="text: CustomerName"> >

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just manipulating variables rather than creating a viewmodel and working with its members. Here's a working example using (pretty much) your code.

```js
function Customer() {
  this.CustomerName = ko.observable(null);
  this.LastModifiedBy = ko.observable(null);
}

function setDefault(m) {
    m.CustomerName('Init');
    m.LastModifiedBy('Init')
}

var myEntities = ko.observableArray()
var model = new Customer();
setDefault(model);
myEntities.push(model)

ko.applyBindings({
  myEntities: myEntities
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach:     myEntities">
  <div data-bind="text:     CustomerName">
  </div>
</div>
```